# Call jQuery function from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Right now I have code that looks like this:

```
function search_ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function searchFetch() {
    var keyword = $('#keyword').val();
    if ( keyword ) {
    $('#datafetch').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          action: 'data_fetch',
          keyword: keyword
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });
    } else {
      $('#datafetch').html( '' );
      $('#datafetch').hide();
    }
  }
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'search_ajax_fetch' );
```

But I am trying to move all the jQuery to an external file, and call this function instead.
But I cannot make it work by moving it to an external file and doing it like this:

```
function search_ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  searchFetch();
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'search_ajax_fetch' );
```

Why isn't this working? The js file is loaded correctly!

Comment: You can't use PHP in a JS file like this: `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>`. You need to use `wp_localize_script()` to make that value available in JS. See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#localize).

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I forgot that part! That solved the problem.